# Использование IronPython в Pycharm

Tags: консоль, pycharm, ironpython

Пробую использовать Pycharm для работы с IronPython.
После установки дистрибутива IronPython на win10 и добавления в Pycharm через (File->Settings->Project Interpreter) код исполняется, однако не удается подключится к Python Console и при переходе на соответствующую вкладку выдает следующие ошибки:

```
"C:\Python\IronPython 2.7\ipy.exe" -X:Frames "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.3\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py" --mode=client --port=50440
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.3\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py", line 33, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_console_utils.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.3\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_thrift.py", line 18, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.3\helpers\pydev\pydev_console\protocol.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.3\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\parser\__init__.py", line 29, in load
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.3\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\parser\parser.py", line 502, in parse
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.3\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_ply\yacc.py", line 331, in parse
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.3\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_ply\yacc.py", line 1106, in parseopt_notrack
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.3\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\parser\parser.py", line 212, in p_struct
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.3\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\parser\parser.py", line 765, in _fill_in_struct
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.3\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\thrift.py", line 103, in gen_init
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.3\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\_compat.py", line 170, in init_func_generator
NotImplementedError
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Соответсвенно в задачах постоянно висит "Connecting to console", а без консоли совсем не могу работать.
Прошу помочь с решением.